# Session state providers performance comparison

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, profiling

I have to change the session storage mode in our existing web application from InProc to other outproc (sessionstate/sql/custom provider) mode. I want to compare the performance of these different `session state providers`. Which will be the best tool which I should use for performance comparison. Also what are the different points/scenarios for which I should compare the `performance of providers`.

Comment: According to [this site](http://www.nullskull.com/a/1611/aspnet-session-dataset-datatable-and-net-class-storage.aspx), `InProc` is the fastest, followed by `StateServer`

Answer (score 3):

Seems that the winner, by far, is Redis when going out of proc: 
[ASP.NET Session State Performance Benchmarks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967682/asp-net-session-state-performance-benchmarks) 
A good thing also is that the Redis session provider is provided by Microsoft

Answer (score 0):

Most web applications are moving to stateless or Redis as a state server. Check out the Microsoft provider nuget package: [Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/05/12/announcing-asp-net-session-state-provider-for-redis-preview-release.aspx)

Redis is an extremely fast and distributed key/value store that lends itself to session and web projects. Most/all (depending on configuration) of the data is held in memory. Redis will be the most performant, but StateServer is the default fallback for decent performance.